# How can I auto save Instagram images to Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, if-this-then-that, instagram

Before June 1st, I have an IFTTT recipe to achieve my goal. However, due to some changes, IFTTT delete my recipe. So my question is how to auto save one's instagram (like https://www.instagram.com/google) into my Google Drive folder?

Edit:
Let me be clear, before June 1st, IFTTT have following recipes:

- IFTTT can save your liked photo into one Google Drive folder
- IFTTT can auto save one account's update photo into Google Drive folder

and also the basic feature:

- backup your self photo into Google Drive

However, after June 1st the first two recipes is deleted from IFTTT which is very useful. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: More than likely, Instagram have changed their API. If so, there isn't any service which will let you do what you want. Complain to Instagram.

Answer (score 3):

Instagram changed their API and IFTTT can no longer support 'this' actions such as 'when I like a photo' or 'when I am tagged in a photo'.

It sucks right?  No one likes when features are taken away.  I hope we can find something soon that compares.